# DRF simpleJWT - Is there anyway to fetch user's data from an access-token with no access to the 'request' param?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to write a custom authentication middleware for Django channels since I'm using JWT for my app's authentication scheme. I'm using the method that is mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/@master.rta/django-channels-web-socket-authentication-approaches-3a56954b4120) article which basically gets user's token in the first request that is made to the websockets and then, in the receive method of the `consumers.py` file, fetches user's data based on that and then pours it in the self.scope['user'] (can't make use of the [token_auth.py](https://gist.github.com/rluts/22e05ed8f53f97bdd02eafdf38f3d60a#file-token_auth-py) method because the UI app is separate..). Now since I have NO ACCESS to the request param that is usually being used in the `views.py` files to get the user's data, is there anyway to get the user's data out of an access token alone??

Answer (score 3):

Hello @Jalal try this.

```
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    from django.db import close_old_connections
    
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.backends import TokenBackend

    class TokenAuthMiddleware:
        """
        Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
        """
    
        def __init__(self, inner):
            self.inner = inner
    
        def __call__(self, scope):
            headers = dict(scope['headers'])
            if b'authorization' in headers:
                try:
                    token_name, token_key = headers[b'authorization'].decode().split()
                    if token_name == 'Token':
                        print(token_key)
                        valid_data = TokenBackend(algorithm='HS256').decode(token_key,verify=False)
                        print(valid_data)
                        scope['user_id'] = valid_data['user_id']
    
                        close_old_connections()
                except Token.DoesNotExist:
                    scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
            return self.inner(scope)
    
    TokenAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

Here `valid_data` return this:

> {'token_type': 'access', 'exp': 1627994463, 'jti':
> '192275bd7fd649758838ave1899e1863', 'user_id': 2}

If you want to fetch more data(like:Username,email,etc) through `access token` then use [Customizing token claims](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html#customizing-token-claims):

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['email'] = user.email
        # ...

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```